# postfix: unable to lookup additional local_recipient_maps

Tags: postfix, email-server

For what i understood from http://www.postfix.org/LOCAL_RECIPIENT_README.html I can add additional recipient for $mydestination, without messing with system users, with this parameter:

```
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps hash:/etc/postfix/localrcpt
```

But even if I created localrcpt, issued 'postmap' and restarted postfix it keep telling me:

```
status=bounced (unknown user:"theUser")
```

$mydestination include $mydomain, so I should be able to accept mail for defined local users. what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, that's evil. **local_recipient_maps** tells Postfix's smtpd (SMTP daemon accepting mails from the internet) which local addresses are to be accepted during the SMTP dialogue. This option is there to prevent backscatter (accepting mails to unknown recipients, and bouncing them afterwards).

But after the mail has been accepted, another daemon (in your case probably **local**) doesn't know what to do with that email.

What you did makes Postfix accept mail for an non-existing local user, and bouncing the mail after accepting it.

Comment: So, doI have to configure 'local' daemon to deliver those emails? I will lurk into docs. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly what you wanted NOT to do in the first place (messing with system users).

Comment: Just want you to know I created a pipe service to procmail in master.cf in order to handle local non-system addresses, and after configured a mailboxes_transport_map everything works as I want. Thank you!